# Derive the recurrence relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, special-functions

Let $P_{m,n}=P_{m,n}(x,y)$ be a polynomial family. Here is some initial terms
$$ P_{0,0}=1, P_{1,0}=2x, P_{0,1}=2y, P_{1,1}=8xy.$$
I  know that the polynomials for any $m,n \geq 0$ satisfies the five  differential recurrence relations
\begin{align}
&n \frac{\partial P_{m,n-1}}{\partial x}=m \frac{\partial P_{m-1,n}}{\partial y},\\
& x \frac{\partial P_{m,n}}{\partial x}=m P_{m,n}+m\frac{\partial P_{m-1,n}}{\partial x},\\
& y\frac{\partial P_{m,n}}{\partial x}=m P_{m-1,n+1}+n \,\frac{\partial P_{m,n-1}}{\partial x},\\
& y \frac{\partial P_{m,n}}{\partial y}=n P_{m,n}+n\frac{\partial P_{m,n-1}}{\partial y},\\
& x\frac{\partial P_{m,n}}{\partial y}=n P_{m+1,n-1}+m \,\frac{\partial P_{m-1,n}}{\partial y}.
\end{align}

Also, they satisfies the differential equation
$$
(1-x^2) \frac{\partial^2 P_{m,n}}{\partial x^2} -x y \frac{\partial^2 P_{m,n} }{\partial x \partial y} -(n+3) x \frac{\partial  P_{m,n}}{\partial x }+m y \frac{\partial  P_{m,n}}{\partial y }+m(m+n+2) P_{m,n}=0,
$$
for any $m,n.$

I need to eliminate all the derivatives and get  pure  recurrence relations for $P_{m,n}$.

By numeric expеriments I guess such recurrence relations
$$
2 (1{+}m{+}n) x P_{m,n}=P_{m+1,n}{-}n(n{-}1)P_{m+1,n-2}{+m(m+2n+1)}P_{m-1,n},\\
2 (1{+}m{+}n) y P_{m,n}=P_{m,n+1}{-}m(m{-}1)P_{m-2,n+1}{+}n(n+2m+1)P_{m,n-1},
$$
but I still  cant prove it.

Any help?

**P.S.** There  is an exact expression

$$
P_{m,n}=m! n! 2^{m+n}  \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{m}{2}} \sum_{j=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} (-1)^{i+j}\frac{(m{+}n{-}i{-}j)!}{i! j! (m{-}2i)! (n{-}2j) 2^{2(i+j)}} x^{m-2i} y^{n-2j}.
$$

Comment: Are we given that $P_{m,n}(x,y)$ is of the form $x^my^n?$  It seems like it should be.

Comment: @Ross Millikan  Yes, In some sence, $P_{m,n}$ is a generalisation of $x^m y^n.$

Comment: Please check your recurrence relations.  If $P_{m,n}(x,y)=c_{m,n}x^my^n$ we have $x\frac{\partial P_{m,n}}{\partial x}=mP_{m,n}$ and two terms in the second relation cancel, leaving the third equal to zero.  The same thing happens in the fourth one involving $y$.

Comment: That is why I was asking if it was a constant times $x^my^n$.  I took that from the first few examples you gave, but it appears it is not in general.

Comment: I give you more examples $$ P_{1,2}=48\,x{y}^{2}-8\,x,\\ P_{2,2}=384\,{x}^{2}{y}^{2}-48\,{x}^{2}-48\,{y}^{2}+8.$$

Comment: I have two questions about your formula for $P_{m,n}$ : 1) how do you define a negative factorial (what is $(m-2i)!$ when $i=m$ ?) ,and 2) are you sure you have a $n-2j$ factor in the denominator ? A $(n-2j)!$ factor would make the expression completely symmetrical.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy   I am sorry - 1)   the upper bounds are $\frac{n}{2}, \frac{m}{2},$ of course.      2) You are right - I miss the factor $x^m y^n $. Now corrected.

Comment: It is still uncorrected on my screen, 5 mins after you write "now corrected". There seems to be a delay

Comment: @ Ewan Delanoy Now everything is ok

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: The correct result for $P$ is $$P_{m,n}(x,y)=m! n!  \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} (-1)^{i+j}\frac{(m+n-i-j)!}{i! j! (m-2i)! (n-2j)!} (2x)^{m-2i} (2y)^{n-2j}.$$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: I have verified that this function satisfies all of the relations above.

Comment: I think you should start first by looking for Appell functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series

Comment: @Nikos Bagis, No, actually it is   Lauricella hypergeometric series $F_B$  but it doesnt help

Comment: If you have an explicit expression what's the problem to check the equality for the coefficients of the corresponding monomials?

Comment: @Andrew You may do it and get +200 to reputation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your polynomials are crying out to be put into a generating function,
$$P = \sum_{m, n \geq 0} P_{m, n} \frac{u^m}{m!} \frac{v^n}{n!}.$$
Working backwards from your explicit formula, set $N = m+n-i-j$, $m' = m-2i, n' = n-2j$ and do routine simplifications to get
$$
\begin{align*}
  P &= \sum_{N \geq 0} \sum_{(i, j, m', n') \vDash N} \binom{N}{i,j,m',n'} (2x)^{m'} (2y)^{n'} (-u^2)^i (-v^2)^j u^{m'} v^{n'} \\
    &= \sum_{N \geq 0} (2xu + 2yv - u^2 - v^2)^N \\
    &= \frac{1}{1 + u^2 + v^2 - 2xu - 2yv}.
\end{align*}
$$
That is,
$$P_{m, n} = m! n! [u^m v^n] \frac{1}{1 + u^2 + v^2 - 2xu - 2yv}.$$

Sometimes in practice you'd be able to prove your interpretation satisfies the above generating function formula independently, which would prove the explicit formula by running the preceding argument backwards.

In any case, your initial recurrences can be packaged up into PDE's involving the $P$ generating function in a standard way. (See e.g. Wilf's *generatingfunctionology* for a nice, though unusual, treatment.) For example,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} P = \sum_{m, n \geq 0} P_{m+1,n} \frac{u^m}{m!} \frac{v^n}{n!}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} u P = \sum_{m, n \geq 0} (m+1) P_{m, n} \frac{u^m}{m!} \frac{v^n}{n!}.$$

Using these observations, your first recurrence relation,
$$n \partial_x P_{m, n-1} = m \partial_y P_{m-1, n},$$
can be repackaged into
$$\partial_{uvx} vP = \partial_{uvy} uP.$$
It's of course easy to have a computer verify this holds with the formula above.

Your five differential recurrence relations translate to
$$
\begin{align*}
  \partial_{uvx} vP &= \partial_{uvy} uP \\
  x \partial_{xu} P &= \partial_u u (\partial_u + \partial_x) P \\
  y \partial_{xuv} P &= \partial_{uv^2} uP + \partial_{xuv} vP \\
  y \partial_{vy} P &= \partial_v v (\partial_v + \partial_y) P \\
  x \partial_{yuv} P &= \partial_v v \partial_{u^2} P + \partial_u u \partial_y.
\end{align*}
$$
Your "pure" differential equation translates to
$$(1-x^2) \partial_{x^2} P - xy \partial_{xy} P - x \partial_{xv} vP - 2x \partial_x P + uy \partial_{uy} P + u \partial_u (\partial_u u + \partial_v v) P = 0.$$
Your "pure" recurrence relations translate to
$$
\begin{align*}
  2x (\partial_u u + \partial_v v + 2) \partial_{uv^2} P
    &= \partial_{u^2 v^2} P - (1+\partial_v v) \partial_{u^2} P + \partial_u u (\partial_u u + 2 \partial_v v + 3) \partial_{v^2} P \\
  2y (\partial_v v + \partial_u u + 2) \partial_{vu^2} P
    &= \partial_{v^2 u^2} P - (1+\partial_u u) \partial_{v^2} P + \partial_v v (\partial_v v + 2 \partial_u u + 3) \partial_{u^2} P.
\end{align*}
$$
All 8 of these relations hold for $P$ above.

These identities correspond to elements of the annihilator of $P$ in the Weyl algebra on 4 variables. These elements are, respectively,
$$
\begin{align*}
  &\partial_{uvx} v - \partial_{uvy} u \\
  &x \partial_{xu} - \partial_u u (\partial_u + \partial_x) \\
  &y \partial_{xuv} - \partial_{uv^2} u - \partial_{xuv} v \\
  &y \partial_{vy} - \partial_v v (\partial_v + \partial_y) \\
  &x \partial_{yuv} - \partial_v v \partial_{u^2} - \partial_u u \partial_{yv} \\
  &(1-x^2) \partial_{x^2} - xy \partial_{xy} - x \partial_{xv} v - 2x \partial_x + uy \partial_{uy} + u \partial_u (\partial_u u + \partial_v v) \\
  &2x (\partial_u u + \partial_v v + 2) \partial_{uv^2} - \partial_{u^2 v^2} + (1+\partial_v v) \partial_v v \partial_{u^2} - \partial_u u (\partial_u u + 2 \partial_v v + 3) \partial_{v^2} \\
  &2y (\partial_v v + \partial_u u + 2) \partial_{vu^2} - \partial_{v^2 u^2} + (1+\partial_u u) \partial_u u \partial_{v^2} - \partial_v v (\partial_v v + 2 \partial_u u + 3) \partial_{u^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Your question--how to derive the last two "pure" recurrence relations from the previous six--is equivalent to asking if the last two elements are in the (left) ideal generated by the first six elements. We can check this in Macaulay2:

```
loadPackage "Dmodules"
W = QQ[x,y,u,v,Dx,Dy,Du,Dv, WeylAlgebra => {x=>Dx, y=>Dy, u=>Du, v=>Dv}]
rP = 1+u^2+v^2-2*x*u-2*y*v
I = RatAnn rP -- the ideal of relations from the explicit formula
J = ideal(Du*Dv*(Dx*v-Dy*u), x*Dx*Du - Du*u*(Du+Dx), y*Dx*Du*Dv-Du*Dv*Dv*u-Dx*Du*Dv*v, y*Dv*Dy-Dv*v*(Dv+Dy), x*Dy*Du*Dv-Dv*v*Du^2-Du*u*Dy*Dv, (1-x^2)*Dx^2-x*y*Dx*Dy-x*Dx*Dv*v-2*x*Dx+u*y*Du*Dy+u*Du*(Du*u+Dv*v))
isSubset(J,I) -- True: first 6 proposed relations hold for explicit formula
isSubset(I,J) -- False: there are more than these 6
f = 2*x*(Du*u+Dv*v+2)*Du*Dv^2-Du^2*Dv^2+(1+Dv*v)*Dv*v*Du^2-Du*u*(Du*u+2*Dv*v+3)*Dv^2
f % J -- 0: 7th relation is implied by first 6!
f // gens J -- write 7th relation in terms of first 6; pages of horrendous mess
```

This counts as a proof, though we have to trust the computer for the hard part. If you can't prove the geometric series formula directly, you could instead prove the other generators of "I" work in your context and presumably simplify the mess the computer had to do to get the 7th relation from the first 6. This does not seem worthwhile, however.

Comment: thanks, very interesting approach, but, this is only a possible way. Did you do such a check? What was Macaulay2's answer?  I dont sure that we have a generanig set for the differential ideal, so the answer can be "No"

Comment: As I said at the bottom, I did have Macaulay2 check that the 7th relation is indeed a consequence of the first 6. (So is the 8th.) This is despite the fact that the full differential ideal of $P$ ("I" in my code) is larger than the one generated by your first 6 [hence, all 8] relations. If you run the code I wrote, it will spit out a generating set for I. It has 10 elements and is not bad.

Comment: Good solution, I trust Macaulay2. Now I have my own  short solution but I like yours one.

Comment: For what it's worth, my solution does contain a simple, direct proof of your "pure" recurrence relation starting from the generating function formula or equivalently the explicit formula, without relying on Macaulay2. Namely, translate the recurrence relation to the PDE $2x(\partial_u u + \ldots)$ and have any CAS check the PDE indeed holds. That approach does not use the six auxiliary relations.

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

From the identity
$$
1=(1-2 (xu+yv)+u^2+v^2)\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty  P_{m,n}  \frac{u^m}{m!}  \frac{v^n}{n!}, 
$$
by equating coefficients to $0$ we get that
\begin{equation}
2(1{+}m) x P_{m,n}{+}2 n y P_{m+1,n{-}1}=P_{m+1,n}{+}m(m{+}1) P_{m-1,n}{+}n(n{-}1) P_{m{+}1,n{-}2} \tag{1}
\end{equation}
By using known differential recurrence relations (and by some  shifting indexes if need ) easy to check that the following hods:
$$
 P_{m,n}+x \frac{\partial P_{m,n}}{\partial x}- y   \frac{\partial P_{m+1,n{-}1}}{\partial x}=m \frac{\partial P_{m+1,n{-}1}}{\partial x}-(n{-}1) \frac{\partial P_{m+1,n-2}}{\partial x}.
$$
Rewrite it in the form
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(x P_{m,n}- y P_{m+1,n{-}1}) =\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(mP_{m-1,n}-(n{-}1)P_{m+1,n-2}).
$$
Integrate
$$
x P_{m,n}- y P_{m+1,n{-}1}=mP_{m-1,n}-(n{-}1)P_{m+1,n-2}+C_{m,n}(y),
$$
where $C_{m,n}(y)$ is some unknown function of one variable $y.$

Again differentiate by $y$ and by simplification we get that $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}C_{m,n}(y)=0,$  thus $C_{m,n}(y)$ is a constant $C_{m,n}.$
Therefore
$$
x P_{m,n}- y P_{m+1,n{-}1}=mP_{m-1,n}-(n{-}1)P_{m+1,n-2}+C_{m,n},
$$
By puting $x=y=0$ we get that $C_{m,n}=0$  and
$$
x P_{m,n}- y P_{m+1,n{-}1}=mP_{m-1,n}-(n{-}1)P_{m+1,n-2}.\tag{2}
$$

Now, multiply $(2)$ by $2n$ and add to $(1)$  we get the first recurrence relation.